# Bar released from upright position rotates about a lower hinge before being caught by a steel cable, how to calculate the tension on the cable?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics

I wish to check the safety factor of a steel cable that I've designed to catch a heavy bar that rotates freely due to the gravitational force acting on it.

From the upright position, I'm assuming that the bar has a rotational velocity of 0rad/s before rotating about a lower hinge (hence, gaining rotational kinetic energy), and comes to a stop when the cable goes from slack (sagging cable) to taut (straight - full length).

I've currently modelled the cable as a spring where the rotational kinetic energy is converted to elastic potential energy within the cable upon a small extension. This may be where I've made a mistake since cables don't alway follow Hooke's law and the elastic extension I've found doesn't seem to account for the momentum. Based on this, I'm guessing that I've gone about this problem the wrong way. I'll attach my working with some example numbers below.

Any help or guidance on this will be hugely appreciated!

[image: Working 1]

[image: Working 2]

Comment: Can you also add the rationale from one step to the next; particularly for the steps in the second figure.

Comment: I would use stress-strain chart to calculate the maximum energy the cable can absorb while staying in the elastic region (or inside its rated load). If the chart is relatively linear that should be pretty easy.

Comment: I haven't studied your calculations. Did you include an impact factor? It could be a significant percentage of the applied static load. If you're capable of experimentation, measurement of the tension member length could help. There may be an energy calculation based on the rebound of the swinging rod that would yield an impact factor.